# Watir wont wait for page to be loaded

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, watir

I am loading a page and then clicking on an element in that page. Currently I am using sleep to click on it but I don't feel that is robust enough (also, it disappears after a while).

```
 on(page1).buttonForNextPage.click
   @myvariable = on(page2).target_link_element.wait_until_present().link.text
```

The wait_until_present() seems to be achieving nothing. If I do not add sleeps the code just races through. Only works with sleep (3) but I want to avoid that.

Also, I am using pageobjects gem for my pages.

Comment: When the code races through, what is the incorrect behaviour that you see? Is `@myvariable` being set to the wrong value?

Comment: I get the Selenium element does not exist code. It can't find target_link_element

Comment: Which version of Page-Object and Watir are you using? Can you also share the definition for `target_link_element` and ideally a page that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Watir 6.5.0 Page object 2.2. target_link_element is defined as td(:target_link, :id => 'someID',:frame=>frame)

Comment: Can you try upgrading Watir to latest? There were a number of fixes in 6.8.x related to not waiting appropriately.

Comment: Hey, I updated to 6.7.X and it works now! If you could add an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest version of Watir, currently v6.8.4. Since v6.5.0, there have been a number of bug fixes that have addressed the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Just for clarification. Watir should wait for pages to be loaded before it goes to the next page by default, right?

Comment: Yes and no. When clicking a button/link that submits a form or starts a navigation, the underlying driver will wait for the page load to finish. If the button/link triggers some JavaScript, which in turn causes the browser to refresh, the driver does not know it needs to wait. However, most of the Watir element calls will wait for the element to appear before taking action/inspecting. In short, most cases will wait but there are some edge cases.